# What's wrong with this c++ code?

Tags: c++, syntax-error

My C++ is a bit rusty so...

```
#include<list>
typedef list<int> foo;
```

that gives me the oh so nice error message:

> test.cpp:2: syntax error before `;' token

What the heck can I even Google for in that...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are expecting the list to be in global namespace. But is defined inside std namespace. Hence either you should use `using namespace std;` or expliictly specify the namespace as `std::list;` I personally prefer the second option.

Comment: Don't forget the using-declaration: "using std::list;".  If I'm referencing something a lot (cout, endl), I'll bring them into the current scope without bringing the rest of std.

Answer (score 14):

The names of the `C++` Standard library are in namespace `std`

```
#include <list>
typedef std::list<int> foo;
```

Answer (score 5):

`list<>` is in the STD namespace. This should work fine:

```
#include<list>
typedef std::list<int> foo;
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could do,

```
#include<list>
using namespace std;
typedef list<int> foo;
```

if you don't want to type `std::` everywhere.

Comment: Actually, I consider this bad advice. (I don't want to start all over The Holy Namespace Debate here, but I stick to my opinion nevertheless.)